# Grails project login plugin

Tags: security, spring, grails, authentication

I am using a Grails project , in which for logging in the site grails plugin(Springsecurity) is used, which checks and authorizes with login id and password . But I don't have any idea that how does it do it , i guess it uses 'j_spring_security_check' . I want to put one more check except the password check related to the ip of the user , how to and where to do it ?

Comment: which plugin you use and under which O.S.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of an appropriate event closure as described in the [docs](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/7%20Events.html#7.3%20Registering%20Callback%20Closures).